# In LangChain, what is an example conversation used for?

Tags: langchain

LangChain [`HumanMessage`s](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/schema/langchain.schema.messages.HumanMessage.html#langchain.schema.messages.HumanMessage) and [`AIMessage`s](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/schema/langchain.schema.messages.AIMessage.html#langchain.schema.messages.AIMessage) have an `example` argument. The documentation describes this argument as

> Whether this Message is being passed in to the model as part of an example conversation.

What is an example conversation?

When might I want to set `example=True`?

Answer (score 1):

The "example conversation" is a dialogue that sets the context for a conversation with a model, guiding its responses in line with the example.

Setting **example=True** indicates that the message is part of a preceding dialogue. It allows you to tailor the model's behavior by providing a reference conversation, for specific needs.

Comment: Just to put some context on the injection point of data in code `messages = [
    SystemMessage(content="You are a helpful AI assistant that answer questions given by me that are related to blood pressure and heart rate, any questions that are not related you simply can't answer."),
    HumanMessage(
        content="Tell me technical facts about yourself. Are you a transformer model? How many billions of parameters do you have?",
        example=True,
        conversations=conversations, # Here's the injected data
    ),
]`